# cassandra 3 node cluster on AWS loading data timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, cassandra

I'm loading data from csv files to a cassandra cluster using cql but I keep getting this error:

```
<ErrorMessage code=1100 [Coordinator node timed out waiting for replica nodes' responses] message="Operation timed out - received only 0 responses.">
```

when I do a nodetool status...I get this:

```
[root@ip-10-205-116-141 bin]# ./nodetool status
Datacenter: us-east
===================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address         Load       Tokens  Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  10.205.117.246  98.85 MB   1       ?       72e2394c-bd17-4fe5-aee5-bf4cf8486153  1c
UN  10.205.119.47   98.89 MB   1       ?       7f39be54-5d74-433c-98e1-8aeff64ff795  1c
UN  10.205.116.141  112.18 MB  256     ?       ce5eb89b-d806-4d70-ab14-99df3bdee7c8  1c

Note: Non-system keyspaces don't have the same replication settings, effective ownership information is meaningless
```

when I do a nodetool info on one node, I get this back...

```
[root@ip-10-205-116-141 bin]# ./nodetool -h 10.205.119.47 info
nodetool: Failed to connect to '10.205.119.47:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused'.
```

Comment: Are you using the copy from command? How are you loading the data?

Comment: yeah...using copy from command...I have 10 csv files that are 1gb each seperated by |. So i'm tryign to import them one at a time...

Comment: Try Biran's cassandra-loader instead https://github.com/brianmhess/cassandra-loader or wait for this improvement https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9302

Comment: @user2061886 Just to clarify on the nodetool error, odds are firewall is blocking the port. Try running nodetool once you've ssh'd into the nodes without supplying the host.

Answer (score 0):

First, before you continue any further it's a bad idea to run with vnodes enabled on some nodes, and disabled on others. Go for all or nothing, so either all nodes are vnodes, or none of them are.

Next, the nodetool error, the firewall will block you if you haven't opened the port and also you need to [enable remote JMX on the node](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/security/secureJmxAuthentication.html), so try sshing into the host and running nodetool locally without suppling an ip or a port number.

Now for the actual import problem, the recommendations made by phact are good, but have you tried doing the import on a subset of the data to see if that success? Thats the place to start. If you try to import 2 rows and that fails it means the client isn't connecting to the nodes at all (check firewall configs etc.). If the 2 record import succeeds split your data up, and increase the timeouts for cassandra (update write_request_timeout_in_ms).